# Trying to get a list of checked items on change_state in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

Using **jsTree** (pre1.0_fix_1), I would like to obtain a list of `id`'s for all the checked items (or better, a JSON object with `id` AND text of each checked item). I will then make an ajax call with this. Additionally, this should happen any time there is a state change of something getting checked or unchecked.

This is what I currently have:

```
$(function(){

  n = $('#colors').jstree({
    "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "checkbox"]
  }).bind("change_state.jstree", function(e, data){
  console.log($('#colors').jstree('get_selected').attr('id'));
  });
});
```

This is just returning '**colors**', from the container's`id`: `<div id="colors">`. I fished around the `data` object, but didn't find it in there (perhaps I missed it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the checked nodes' JSON you should be using `get_checked` and not `get_selected`. Try this:

```
    var checked = $("#colors").jstree("get_checked",null,true);
    var checked_json = [];
    $(checked).each(function (i,node) {
        var id = $(node).attr("id");
        var text = $(node).attr("text");
        var node_json = { 
            "id" : id, 
            "text" : text 
        };
        checked_json.push(node_json);
    });
```

After that `checked_json` will contain an array of of id+text objects which you could send to the server.

Comment: Very useful thanks - there are a couple of typos though - `"id" : id _id`, should just be `"id" : id,` and the last line should be `});`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks, I didn't notice that for some reason.