# Get Checked Nodes in a jsTree When Checking/Unchecking Parent Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jstree, multi-level

Note: I have already read the following threads:

- [Get checked nodes in a jsTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322069/get-checked-nodes-in-a-jstree)
- [How to get checked nodes in jquery jstree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268306/how-to-get-checked-nodes-in-jquery-jstree?rq=1)
- [Trying to get a list of checked items on change_state in jstree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544820/trying-to-get-a-list-of-checked-items-on-change-state-in-jstree?rq=1)

I have a multilevel jstree with multiple sibling parent nodes and several children under each parent node.

Whenever any node gets checked/unchecked, I want to receive the list of all checked nodes. I did this using the following method:

```
$("#jstree-picker").on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    console.log(data.selected);
});
```

When I check/uncheck any of the leaf nodes (lowest-level children), the above code prints out the list of all selected nodes correctly. However, when I check/uncheck a parent node, all its children get checked/unchecked correctly, but they do not show up in the list of selected nodes!

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. "selected" and "checked" are different things. I don't know exactly what selected does, but checked is what I was looking for.

```
$("#jstree-picker").on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    console.log($("#jstree-picker").jstree(true).get_checked());
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to get unchecked nodes?? I tries get_unchecked() but it is not working